# OData annotation is missing for Microsoft.AspNet.OData response

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

I have developed two `OData` endpoints with node.js & C# respectively. And I found that the returned value for the C# one has some `OData`annotation missing.

The returned value of the node.js one:

[image]

The returned value of the C# one:

[image]

For both implementation, I am using the same data model, having the same attribute.

[image]

For the C# implementation, I am using Microsoft.AspNet.OData library. Is there any configuration I need to do to make the highlighted annotations (@odata.id, @odata.editLink) to show up?

[image]

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code or errors, copy and paste them into your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but it might help:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn260745.aspx
>
> The specification states the following:
>
> > *The odata.context annotation returns the context URL (see [OData-Protocol]) for the payload.*
> >
> > This URL can be absolute or relative.
>
> OData in the specified Microsoft implementations (section 1.3)
> partially supports this feature.
>
> The name of the odata.context
> annotation is "odata.metadata" and is written without the leading "@".
> The contents of the odata.metadata annotation differs from that of the
> odata.context annotation prescribed in [OData4.0-1Protocol] as
> described below in sections 2.1.9.1 through 2.1.9.9.
>
> Section 4.5.1 of the specification also states the following:
>
> > *The odata.context annotation MUST also be included for entities whose entity set cannot  be determined from the context URL of the collection.*
>
> OData in the specified Microsoft implementations (section 1.3) does
> not support this feature. Entity sets can always be determined from
> the metadata URL of the collection and MUST NOT be present for
> individual entities within a collection or collections within an
> entity.